# AngularJS: get protected JSON with auth headers

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest, angular-http-auth

I have a JSON file generated by the server and to access that JSON via URL within the browser I need to log in providing username and password.

Now I am trying to get that JSON with Angular, although can't find working solution.
What I already have:

```
$scope.dane = [];

$http.jsonp('myURLwithUserAndPass?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
  .success(function(data) {
    console.log('DATA pass');
    $scope.dane = data.products; // response data
  }).error(function() {
    console.log('DATA failed');
  });
```

This produces errors in the console:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token"

and "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/json: "myURLwithUserAndPass?callback=angular.callbacks._0"."

I have tried adding auth headers in the config like following:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + myusername + ':' + mypassword;
```

...but it doesn't help.
I've also tried passing username and password in the URL like that:

```
$http.jsonp('myURLwithUserAndPass?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&userID=SomeUSER&password=SomePSWD ').
```

Any help on how can I access that JSON?

Comment: What kind of authentication? Basic, OAuth ...?

Comment: `username:password` has to be base64 encoded

Comment: try to do that and tell what you see in your browser:
notice: add this line after `console.log('DATA pass');`
`console.log(data);`